# Program to find line segment and bezier curve intersection

Tags: javascript, geometry

Consider the given image of the soccer field

[image]

As you can see in the image the various ball movements, some of them are curved(i.e. in case of (1), (2), (3) in the image)) and some may not(i.e a line(4)),

so I need to find the intersection points of ball path with goalline and sideline. Sometimes the input may not be a curve(i.e a line) like in case of (4) given image

I have written a program, I have no clue what is wrong - is this right way to solve this kind of program.

if yes then, how to convert bezier curve into an equation for better solving

considering the given as

```
beizer curve eqaution -> a(x*x) + b*x + c
and line segment equation -> y = y1 + m(x-x1)
```

//maxCurvedPoint is the topmost of the curve

```
var getIntersectionPoint = function (room, ballFromPosition, ballToPosition, maxCurvePoint) 
{
    var linepoints = [[m1,n1], [m2, n2], [m3, n3], [m4, n4]];

    //converting three points(ballFromPosition, maxCurvePoint, ballToPosition) into the quadratic equation (Bezier curve) --(1)
    //getting the equation of the line segment using the linepoints --(2)

    //equating (1) and (2) and getting a quadratic equation and solving and finding intersection points
    return intersectionPoint;
}

// solves //(-b(+-)sqrt(b*b - 4ac)/2ac)
function solve(a, b, c) 
{        
 //check curve intersects line or not
   if((Math.pow(b, 2) - (4 * a * c)) >= 0) 
   {
       result1 = (-1 * b + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - (4 * a * c))) / (2 * a);
       result2 = (-1 * b - Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - (4 * a * c))) / (2 * a);
       return [result1, result2];
   } 

   return [];
}
```

Can anyone help me with this? Also is the most curve point can be called vertex of the curve?

Comment: You might be getting an output because the equation describes an infinite parabola, whereas your "parabolas" are just *sections* of these infinite parabolas. You should check the intersection coordinate range.

Comment: Two suggestions, one make this easier to read via helper functions (e.g. `const square = n => Math.pow(n, 2);` rather than inlining all the math and two because of a quirk of the JavaScript language K&R style braces are strongly preferred over GNU-style braces. I bet if you at least do the first you'll likely spot your problem.

Comment: You should first understand the concept of a parametric curve equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find it easier to work with vector equations since the algebra will be rotation-invariant (hence you don't have to re-write the code to deal with e.g. a "horizontal" parabola).

---

**1. Curve representation + Intersection test**

Consider a [*quadratic Bezier curve*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Quadratic_B%C3%A9zier_curves) with endpoints `A, C`, control point `B` and parameter `t`:

[image]

[image]

And an *infinite line* with source `O`, direction `D` and parameter `s`:

[image]

Equating `P` and `R` give a pair of quadratic simultaneous equations, which can be re-arranged to eliminate `s` and find the parabolic parameter `t`:

[image]

Solve this quadratic equation for `t`, and only accept real roots in the range `[0, 1]`. This ensures that any intersection point is *always* on the segment itself.

---

**2. Dealing with line segments**

You can also restrict the intersection point to a line *segment*, by computing `s` from `t` using the equations above, and limiting its value - which equals the distance along the line from `O` if `D` is normalized.

---

**3. Computing the control point B**

Note that a general value of the control point `B` will not give a *symmetrical* parabola. To compute `B` for a general symmetric curve:

[image]

Defining the variables:

- `M`: midpoint of `AB`
- `n`: *clockwise normal* to the direction `AC`
- `q`: *signed bulge distance* - absolute value is the distance from `M` to the midpoint of the curve
- `k`: signed distance from `M` to `B`

[image]

A surprisingly simple result.

---

**4. Sample C# (-style) code**

```
public static Vector2[] computeIntersection
(
   Vector2 A, Vector2 C, double q,    // parabola segment
   Vector2 O, Vector2 P               // line segment
)
{
   // quadratic solve
   double[] solve(double a, double b, double c)
   {
      double d = b * b - 4.0 * a * c;
      if (d < 0.0) // imaginary roots - no intersection at all
         return null;

      if (d > 0.0) // two distinct real roots
      {
         double sd = Math.Sqrt(d);
         return new double[2] { (-b + sd) / (2.0 * a),
                                (-b - sd) / (2.0 * a) };
      }
      else // only one (line segment is tangent to curve)
      {
         return new double[1] { -b / (2.0 * a) };
      }
   }

   // cross product (in-case undefined)
   double cross(Vector2 i, Vector2 j)
   {
      return i.x * j.y - i.y * j.x;
   }

   // validity check for t and s
   bool valid(double v)
   {
      return (v >= 0.0) && (v <= 1.0);
   }

   // compute control point B
   Vector2 E = C - A;
   Vector2 M = 0.5 * (A + C);
   Vector2 N = (new Vector2(E.y, -E.x)).normalize();
   Vector2 B = M + (2.0 * q) * N;

   // solving for t
   Vector2 D = P - O;
   bool useX = Math.Abs(D.X) > Math.Abs(D.Y);
   double[] T = solve(cross(A + C - 2.0 * B, D),
                      cross(B - A, D) * 2.0,
                      cross(A - O, D));
   if (T == null) return null;

   Vector2[] I = new Vector2[2];
   int c = 0;

   for (int i = 0; i < T.Length; i++)
   {
      // check if t is within curve range
      double t = T[i];
      if (!valid(t)) continue;

      // solve for s and check if is within line range
      double u = (1 - t) * (1 - t);
      double v = 2 * t * (1 - t);
      double w = t * t;
      double s = useX ? ((u * A.X + v * B.X + w * C.X - O.X) / D.X)
                      : ((u * A.Y + v * B.Y + w * C.Y - O.Y) / D.Y);
      if (!valid(s)) continue;

      // compute the corresponding intersection point
      I[c++] = O + s * D;
   }

   // only return valid solutions
   if (c == 0) return null;
   Array.Resize(ref I, c);
   return I;
}
```

Comment: @ meowgoesthedog, thanks for the reply, but I don't have the control point, but I have only the vertex of the curve, is there any way to get the control point

Comment: @paradox that was exactly the aim of the third part of my post - to **compute** the control point when you know the vertex (or in the symmetrical case, the "bulge" distance).

Comment: @ meowgoesthedog,  what if it is not infinite line but a line segment, then in that case

Comment: @paradox I also explained that in the second part - once you have the parabolic parameter `t`, you can compute the *line* parameter `s` using the equations, and test if `s` is in a required range.

Comment: @ meowgoesthedog, can you please paste the sample code

Comment: @paradox would you like to attempt this first? I'll post some code if you're stuck, but the equations are pretty simple to implement. Also, would you accept code in another language, e.g. Java / C#? I'm rusty with JS.

Comment: @ meowgoesthedog, it is okay to post in Java/C#,  ill try to implement

Comment: @paradox I updated with sample code, hope it helps if you're stuck.

Answer (score 1):

If you translate and rotate all the endpoints in such a way that the line segment becomes `(0, 0)-(d, 0)`, the problem simplifies.

Let the control points be `(Xk, Yk)`, `k= 0, 1, 2`. The intersections with the axis X are obtained by solving for `t` the quadratic equation

```
Y0 (1-t)² + 2 Y1 t(1-t) + Y2 t² = 0.
```

The corresponding abscissas are given by

```
X0 (1-t)² + 2 X1 t(1-t) + X2 t² = 0.
```

You can check if these belong to the interval `[0, d]`. Then apply the reverse rotation and translation.

---

**Addendum: intersection of two quadratic Beziers**

The vector equation of one of the curves can be written

```
P = P0 (1 - t)² + 2 P1 t (1 - t) + P2 t²
  = P0 + 2 (P1 - P0) t + (P0 - 2 P1 + P2) t².
```

If you apply the affine change of coordinates such that the reference frame becomes `(P0, P1 - P0, P0 - 2 P1 + P2)`, the equation simplifies to

```
X = 2t
Y = t²
```

which is the implicit equation

```
X² = 4Y.
```

Now by applying the same transform to the control points of the second curve and plugging the parametric equations in the above, you get a quartic equation in `t` (square of a quadratic polynomial on one side, quadratic polynomial on the other).

There are closed-form formulas for the roots of a quartic equation, and there can be four of them. After selecting the real roots in `[0, 1]`, you evaluate the `t` parameter of the first curve and also check membership in `[0, 1]`.

Don't forget to restore the original coordinates.